# Old chime doorbell - how to connect to a switch to silence it overnight

Tags: doorbell

I have an old doorbell and need to connect it to a switch. I get some people ringing at 4am and need to be able to disconnect it. Can anybody help, please?

Which cable is the one to use? and how to do it, please?

[image]

Comment: IDK for sure, but I'd start by disconnecting the black wire from the terminal and see if that does the trick.  If it does, reconnect it, cut it, and wire in a single switch with some extra wire to get the switch where you want it.

Comment: Note that this unit originally had two chimes. The idea was that when the front door button was pushed, the coil would be energized to hit the missing chime; releasing the button would let the spring rebound to hit the other, resulting in a "bing-bong" two-note sound. Pressing the back door button would energies the coil the other way hitting the surviving chime, and then returning more weakly so the rebound did not hit the missing chime, sounding only the one-note "bong". Occupants would thus know which door to go to.

Answer (score 2):

If you have easy access to this bell module and if it's normally open as pictured, the easiest way to silence it would be to shove a pencil eraser onto the end of the hammer.  One big enough to completely immobilize the hammer.  Then in the morning you just remove it.

If you want to do it with a switch you can cut *any* of the wires, and use an automotive or marine switch (12V) or one for electronics projects, in line with the cut wire.  (Note: "Any wire" assumes there is only one door with a button.  If there is a second one, you'll have to use certain wires.)

Adding a picture of where the hammer is, as requested in comment.

[image]

The idea is to prevent the end of the hammer from hitting the chime.  The other chime is missing, and the other end of the hammer does not need covering as a result.

Comment: @Huesmann  I mean, sure, reaching up and flicking a switch is X work and reaching up and sticking something between the hammer and chime is 2X or 3X.  But X is pretty small right?  And we're all evading the question of why 4am visitors are so frequent and why disabling the doorbell would thwart them, whatever their intentions are?

Comment: @jay613 I was talking about the effort of sticking a pencil eraser on the hammer every day.  IDK why my comment was deleted...

Comment: @Huesmann I get random comments deleted without explanation.   Sometimes I think it's a moderator deleting something irrelevant.  But your comment was perfectly relevant.  Anyway, who are you or I to say how much effort is too much effort in making it just a tiny bit harder for people to wake you up at 4am every day?   Which is to say the question becomes more ridiculous each time I think about it.  :)   People are ringing your bell at 4am?   Why?  What is their motivation?  And how will silencing your doorbell stop them from whatever it is they are up to?

Comment: @jay613 Thank you. That's very kind. It seems to have been manipulated as I removed the hammer and remaining dong, and still makes noise. I"ll cut one of the inner dark orange cables and see if it works. Then, I"ll connect via a one way switch.

Comment: @jay613 no kidding—who rings someone's doorbell at 4am?  Only a psychopath!  OP, do you have lots of kids in your neighborhood who like to prank people, or something?